# Why the amount of ethers in the block chain(Private) increasing?

Tags: mining, ether, coinbase

I have set up a private block chain. I started to mine on this network. Now the number of ethers in the coinbase account is continuously increasing. How is it getting ethers? Do the blockchain generate new ethers to reward the miner? 
If so wouldn't it result in the inflation.

Comment: since there are already 3 answers, you did not accept any of them and you did not provide any further comment, please accept one of the existing answers or tell us what is you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mining is rewarded, even in a private blockchain, 5 Eth for each block.

In your case, you are the only miner, so you get 5 ETH almost continuously...

For more information concerning the minig :

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining

Comment: Does this means new ethers are added into the system, even in the public chain?

Comment: yep, just edited the answer for more info

Comment: Please add that a private blockchain has its own currency. Ether on a private blockchain are not Ethers of Homestead (the production one)

Answer (score 4):

In Ethereum you get 5 Ether as reward if you are the one who first solves the puzzle and, consequently, you are the one who adds the new block to the blockchain.

This happens on any network, be it private or public, since it is part of the Ethereum protocol and code.

Inflation does not take place because the Ether gathered on a private network can only be spent on gas in that private network and cannot be exchanged for real money. Only the ether from the public network has real world value.

If we talk about inflation on the public network, it doesn't happen since the demand for ether is bigger than the rate with which is produced.

Comment: It is giving me too much ethers at a low difficulty. Only 30 blocks mined and I got 20000000 ethers. How can I reduce the amount of ethers I get

Comment: @RameshPareek please ask it as a separate question on the site and not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The Ether is a reward for mining, on *any* chain, the system always works the same. It does not matter whether you mine a private, a testnet or the public network chain.

However, the mined Ether on a testnet or private blockchain can not be used on the public blockchain. So, to answer your question, no: this does not increase inflation, because to mine *real* Ether, you would have to mine the main network.